# warning returns while using sudo apt-get update, how to fix

Tags: 14.04, updates, mariadb

```
W: http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key 199369E5404BD5FC7D2FE43BCBCB082A1BB943DB uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, but just a warning. Contact the repository owner and ask him to fix the problem. For now you can ignore the warning or find a more well maintained PPA providing the software, if possible.